# How i recover my icloud username and password

Tags: iphone

My device is iPhone 4. I forgot my icloud username and password. How can i recover my username and password ? Would you please help me ? Its important as i cant use my device.

Comment: Why can't you use your device? Did you forget your device password or are you in the process of activating a 2nd hand (or reinstalled) phone? Are you logged into your iCloud account on another computer?

Answer (score 3):

Try this site: [Find your Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid?app_type=ext&app_id=93&returnURL=https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa&language=US-EN).

> If you can't remember your Apple ID, just provide us with some information and we'll find it for you. Then we'll help you reset your password.

Answer (score -1):

go to google chrome on your computer.
right on the screen go to controle googlechrome+parametrage
after mot de passe :
and you will find all your password and link related to you your browsing