# Is it possible to recover iCloud without the email

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password

I lost my iPhone iCloud since I changed my device to Android but I can't even remember the iCloud email now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157978

Answer (score 1):

See [Recover Your Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) or [iCloud Recovery](https://www.icloud.com/recovery). You will need at least the phone number associated with the iCloud account.

See also [How i recover my icloud username and password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157978/how-i-recover-my-icloud-username-and-password)